How do Ocean Ecosystems support high trophic level predators?
Ocean Ecosystems have carnivores that can exclusively hunt other carnivores. We know that Otodus Megalodon occupied such a high tropic level that it ate animals that would've eaten today's orcas.
In terrestrial ecosystems, large carnivores hardly ever target smaller ones, rather opting to target herbivores. Of course, in rare instances, a lion would target an adult cheetah, but ocean carnivores have adaptations to target others (eg. Orca's using waves to knock a seal into the ice, Great White Sharks leaping out the water to ambush a seal)
I'm wondering how oceans can support so many carnivores at higher tropic levels and what environmental conditions make carnivore hunting carnivores less common in terrestrial ecosystems. (The Morrison Formation had a lot of carnivores but Ceratosaurus and Saurophaganax aren't believed to have had a predator prey relationship like Brygmophyster and Megalodon)

Welcome. I think your question contains some mistaken assumptions and some conflated ideas. 1) terrestrial carnivores do eat other carnivores (e.g., multiple vertebrate groups including many canines, snakes, raptors, and even felines and primates). 2) big size is not automatically the most important/relevant indicator of trophic level (e.g., bats, ocelots). 3) your ultimate question is really framed as 2  (site policy is that posts should ask only 1 question, so please edit) -- 1 is about abundance (despite the rest of your post focusing on size or frequency)  and 2 is about frequency again.

I would suggest 1) editing your post to focus on one concept/question and 2) if possible, trying to look into and include any support for your underlying premises (e.g.,that higher trophic level consumption is rarer on land). Both will improve your question and will help any potential answer writer provide a more directed response to address your core interest. As of now, I think any potential answer would have to first address some of the issues I have laid out. So, please [edit] as you're able, and if you haven't already check out our [tour] and [help] pages. Thanks!

look up secondary consumer, tertiary consumer, quaternery consumer, and apex predator. because your assumptions about the land is just wrong.
